# Use asp.net button onclick method instead of submitting form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net Button control which I want to use to insert comments in my page. When i click on button, I want it to call a method instead of submitting the form. How do i achieve this?

This is what i have tried so far -

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <script runat="server">    
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      //Do some stuff here   
 }
 </script>
  <head>title and other css links go here</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="false">
        //Some other asp.net controls go here
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Comment" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any other way to achieve what I am doing? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Which method? JavaScript, server-side? And what's wrong with postback?

Comment: I am using C#. Not javascript. I am having multiple buttons to do different insertions in different tables. Hence I do not want postback. I will go with the postback option if nothing else works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know exactly what you are meaning.... I think you are asking for how to insert a comment into an `aspx` via a `shout box`???... Maybe?

Here is the code to insert whatever you want to type(a comment) into your form from a "method"... although it uses a lot more than just a single method.. this is the simplest way I can think of...

This is your `default.aspx` (notice `no master` page here)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>AJAX Example for comment</title>
 <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="page">
<div id="main">
  <div id="shoutbox">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>
  <p>Here's what everyone is saying:</p>
  <p>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ShoutBoxPanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblShoutBox" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000">
        </asp:Timer>
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddShout"
            EventName="Click" />
      </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </p>
  <p>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ShoutBoxPanel2" runat="server"
        UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <p class="label">Name:</p>
        <p class="entry">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"
              MaxLength="15" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
              runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name is required."
              ControlToValidate="txtUserName" Display="Dynamic" 
              CssClass="error">
          </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </p>
        <p class="label">Shout:</p>
        <p class="entry">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtShout" runat="server"
              MaxLength="255" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" 
              runat="server" ErrorMessage="Shout is required."
              ControlToValidate="txtShout" Display="Dynamic" 
              CssClass="error">
          </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddShout" runat="server" Text="Add Shout" 
            onclick="btnAddShout_Click" />
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"
            DynamicLayout="False">
          <ProgressTemplate>
            <img src="Images/spinner.gif" alt="Please Wait" />
             Comment...
          </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is your C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShoutItemList shoutBox;
    if (Application["ShoutBox"] == null)
    {
        shoutBox = new ShoutItemList();
        Application.Add("ShoutBox", shoutBox);
    }
    else
    {
        shoutBox = (ShoutItemList)Application["ShoutBox"];
        lblShoutBox.Text = shoutBox.Display();
    }
    if (ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack != true)
        txtUserName.Focus();
}


protected void btnAddShout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShoutItem shout = new ShoutItem();
    shout.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
    shout.Comment = txtShout.Text;
    shout.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    Application.Lock();
    ShoutItemList shoutBox = (ShoutItemList)Application["ShoutBox"];
    shoutBox.Add(shout);
    Application.UnLock();

    lblShoutBox.Text = shoutBox.Display();
    txtShout.Text = "";
    txtShout.Focus();
}
}
public class ShoutItem
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
public class ShoutItemList
{
private List<ShoutItem> shoutList = new List<ShoutItem>();

private void Purge()
{
    DateTime purgeTime = DateTime.Now;
    purgeTime = purgeTime.AddMinutes(-3);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < shoutList.Count)
    {
        if (shoutList[i].Timestamp <= purgeTime) shoutList.RemoveAt(i);
        else i += 1;
    }
}

public void Add(ShoutItem shout)
{
    Purge();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    shoutList.Insert(0, shout);
}

public string Display()
{
    Purge();
    StringBuilder shoutBoxText = new StringBuilder();
    if (shoutList.Count > 0)
    {
        shoutBoxText.AppendLine("<dl>");
        foreach (ShoutItem shout in shoutList)
        {
            shoutBoxText.Append("<dt>" + shout.UserName + " (");
            shoutBoxText.Append(shout.Timestamp.ToShortTimeString() + ")</dt>");
            shoutBoxText.AppendLine("<dd>" + shout.Comment + "</dd>");
        }
        shoutBoxText.AppendLine("</dl>");
    }
    return shoutBoxText.ToString();
}
}
```

This will allow you to insert whatever comment you want. You can modify this code to your own please....

Let me know if this is the answer you seek.

Comment: Yes this is very similar to what I want to achieve. Thank you. Can you please explain me where the comments are being stored? and how do I extend the duration of comments before they are purged?

Comment: @newguy Well in the example I gave you it isn't being stored anywhere. It's ran off of visual studios virtual server and once the browser is closed the comments go away... I think.. And please anyone correct me if I am wrong. I don't really know what would happen if you gave it a domain name and paid a host and threw the site up there like it is now.... To the original question though is that you use a database like MySQL, Oracle or in this case I'd say MS SQL. http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/02/24/creating-a-simple-shoutbox-with-multiline-textbox.aspx

Comment: @newguy Also, if you don't know much about databases and this was only being used for something small... you could use an access database. It would be cheaper I guess.. And a lot easier to code maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Use the button's OnClientClick, like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Comment" OnClientClick="return javascriptFunction();" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

then your javascript function would look like this

```
function javascriptFunction() {
  //do something here
  return false; //if you don't want the form to POST to the server, leave this as false, otherwise true will let it continue with the POST

}
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain why do we need to call javascript function? Does the onclientclick event stop the form from being submitted?

Comment: I assumed you wanted to do something if the button was clicked. If you don't want the button to do anything then just return false in your clientclick event. Am I misunderstanding your intention?

Comment: Yes you are right. I do want the button to insert records in my database. which will be handled by the button1_click function. I am sorry, but i dont understand why did you suggest to use onclientclick method?

Comment: If you don't want the whole form to get reloaded like in a normal post back, then you have to either use JavaScript with an AJAX type of server interaction or possibly use an update panel which just hides the JavaScript AJAX implementation.

Comment: Ok. I am not very familiar to AJAX. I think I will have to use the postback option. So assuming i use this, will my code written in Button1_click be handled after the page is reloaded?

Comment: When clicking Button1, it performs a "POST" to the server, including information for ASP.NET that you want to call the method Button1_Click. The reloading of the page occurs after the server responds with the new HTML. It appears there is magic occurring here, but all of this is built on top of HTTP.